# Is there a GCC option for printing headers DIRECTLY included by a source file?

Tags: c++, gcc, header-files

I want a command that will print the headers directly included by a source file.  I want it to print their full paths, so it's not enough for me to just scan the source text for include directives and print those.  GCC has the `-H` option that does something like this; but that prints indirectly included headers too.  I don't want to digest that down to the information I want, because running the `-H` analysis takes extra time I don't want to spend, and because there might be multiple appearances of one filename in different directories in the `-H` output, which would be awkward for me to automatically handle.

Is there a command, using GCC or some program that's commonly available alongside GCC, that given

```
#include "stuff.h"
#include <memory>
/* a lot more code, but no more include directives */
```

in a .cpp file, and also given my normal set of `-I` options, will produce

```
/opt/stufflib/include/stuff.h
/usr/include/c++/5.2.1/memory
```

or the like—providing me with exactly one file path per include directive?

If not, then I guess I will just have to duplicate GCC's header file search logic with some code of my own...

Comment: No, but you can easily filter the output of `g++ -H` (`gcc -H`) to show only what you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Since the -H gcc preprocessor flag will show the included files with indentation to represent how deep the #include stack is, you can filter the output by something like this:

```
g++ -H --std=c++11 test.cpp 2>&1 | grep "^\.[^\.]"
```

Comment: Note:  This will exclude headers already included indirectly.  For example, if you included <iostream> first and then <string>, it would only print <iostream> (since iostream uses string).  If you included them in reverse order, this command would give back both.

Comment: Haha I hadn't thought of actually paying attention to those dots.  It seems obvious now.  I still lean toward writing my own thing to minimize the running time, but this seems like a good fallback!